# Uncaught TypeError: App.Routers.Maintenances.MyRouter is not a constructor

Tags: jquery, mysql, backbone.js, underscore.js, ruby-on-rails-7

I am using backbone js as frontend in rails 7 application. In index.html file I have called backbone main file. code is coming in this file. But here I have initialise router file. In which getting error of Router is not a constructor.

In index.html.haml file

```
- content_for :javascript do
  - javascript_include_tag 'backbone/estimate_repair', defer: true, type: "module"
```

In app/javascript/backbone/estimate_repair.js

```
//= require ./templates
//= require ./templates/maintenances/estimate_repair
//= require ./models
//= require ./views

//= require ./views/maintenances/estimate_repair
//= require ./routers

window.App = {
  Models: {},
  Collections: {},
  Routers: {
    Maintenances: {}
  },
  Views: {},
  init: () => {
    new App.Routers.Maintenances.MyRouter();
    Backbone.history.start();
  }
};
```

In app/javascript/backbone/routers/maintenances/MyRouter.js.coffee

```
App.Routers.Maintenances ||= {}

class App.Routers.Maintenances.MyRouter extends Backbone.Router

initialize: (options = {}) ->
  @estimate_router_view = newApp.Views.Maintenances.EstimateRepair.MyView()
```

Some time errors differ i.e. 'App is not defined' and when I defined it as an empty hash it showed "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.' at App.Routers".

Comment: Please share the code in your `routers.js` as well.

Comment: @Julian I have shared code please help me to resolve it.

Comment: Does `MyRouter.js` look exactly as shown here? There is no indentation?

Comment: @Julian actually I missed it, now it's updated. Currently it is in coffeescript, I have tried it with only js as well with changed syntax, showed same error.

Comment: I am facing new issue as well that JST is not defined in backbone view while rendering template.

Comment: The updated `MyRouter.js` is not valid CoffeeScript; the `initialize` method would have to be indented for it to be valid. Besides, whether it is indented in your actual code or not, I do not have enough information to determine where your problems are originating. Regarding the problems, your question lacks focus. You have already named three errors that you encounter, and solving all the problems likely does not fit in a single answer. Please review https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and see whether you can make your question more focused and reproducible.

Comment: @Julian thanks for your suggestion. I will work on it.